# Filtering Levels of JSON in JavaScript recursively keeping children

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm trying to filter a JSON in JavaScript on all levels. I want to keep the "name" of each of the entries at each level based on if it is present in an array. If it isn't present at a certain level, continue through the children.

Accepted names:

```js
var accepted = ["top", "first", "three"]
```

Original JSON:

```
{
    "name": "top", 
    "children": [{
        "name": "first",
        "children": [{
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }, {
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }, {
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "first",
        "children": [{
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }, {
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }, {
            "name": "second",
            "children": [{ "name": "three" }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

New JSON:

```
{
    "name": "top",
    "children": [{
        "name": "first",
        "children": [
            { "name": "three" },
            { "name": "three" },
            { "name": "three" }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "first",
        "children": [
            { "name": "three" },
            { "name": "three" },
            { "name": "three" }
        ]
    }]
}
```

What I've done:

```js
var previous = ""
function loop(a) {
    if (previous.name == a.name) {
        previous = a
        previous['true_children'] = []
    }
    if (accepted.includes(a.name)) {
        previous['true_children'].push(a)
        if (a.children != null) {
            previous = a
            previous['true_children'] = []
        }
    }
    Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(loop); 
}
```

My overall thinking for accomplishing this was to create a `true_children` property that could be iterated through the JSON rather than `children`. This new property could then only contain the filtered levels from the JSON.

However, my code seems to append the `first` once to `true_children` at the first level and again at the second level. Is there a fix for this or a better method to accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide clarification on 1) what is the expected answer when `accepted = ["first", "three"]`? And 2) what is the expected answer when `accepted = []`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your desired output with the following solution, hope that helps!

```js
const accepted = [ "top", "first", "three"];

const data = { "name": "top", 
    "children": [
    {
    "name": "first",
    "children": [
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "first",
    "children": [
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "second",
        "children":[
            {
            "name": "three"
            }
        ]
        }

    ]
    }
    ]
}

function buildOutput(input, accepted) {
  const filtered = Object.keys(input).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if(currentValue === 'name' && accepted.find(x => input[currentValue] === x)) {
      accumulator[currentValue] = input[currentValue];
      if(input['children']){
        accumulator['children'] = input['children'].map(x => buildOutput(x, accepted)).filter(x => x);
        if(!accumulator['children'].length){
          accumulator['children'] = flattenChildren(input['children']).map(x => buildOutput(x, accepted)).filter(x => x);
        }
      }
    } 
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(filtered).length ? filtered : null;
}

function flattenChildren(children) {
  return children.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.concat(currentValue.children), []);
}

console.log(buildOutput(data, accepted));
```

Answer (score 1):

For JSON string, the filtering can be done during parsing :

```js
var accepted = ["top", "first", "three"], json = '{"name":"top","children":[{"name":"first","children":[{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]},{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]},{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]}]},{"name":"first","children":[{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]},{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]},{"name":"second","children":[{"name":"three"}]}]}]}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => k == 'name' && !accepted.includes(v) ? void 0 :
                  v.children && v.children.length === 1 && !v.name ? v.children[0] : v)

console.log( obj )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursive solution, that is hopefully not to hard to understand.

```js
var accepted = ["top", "first", "three"],
    data = {"name": "top", "children": [{"name": "first", "children": [{"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}, {"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}, {"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}]}, {"name": "first", "children": [{"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}, {"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}, {"name": "second", "children": [{"name": "three"}]}]}]};

function transform(accepted, data) { 
  const children = data.children || [],
        result = { name: data.name, children: [] },
        isAccepted = accepted.includes(data.name);

  children.forEach(child => {
    child = transform(accepted, child);
    const children = Array.isArray(child) ? child : [child];
    result.children.push(...children);
  });

  // Guard against data that isn't accepted.
  if (!isAccepted) return result.children;

  // Delete the children key if the array is empty.
  if (!children.length) delete result.children;

  return result;
}

console.log(transform(accepted, data));
```